# Ставить ли двоеточие после слова "предложение" при редактировании вопросов?

Tags: обсуждение

Ставить ли двоеточие после слова "предложение" при редактировании вопросов?

Подробности здесь:
[Двоеточие перед подлинным выражением, которое включено в авторское предложение в качестве его члена](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447370/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2). Там же можете высказaть ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Если это нужно, чтобы отделить вопрос от цитаты, я бы ставил:

> Как правильно В или НА здесь: «Я поехал *** Украину»?

Где и без двоеточия не создается никаких помех для понимания, я бы не ставил:

> Нужно ли в «Ай да Пушкин!» ставить запятую?

Comment: Мой вопрос уже. Заголовок такой: *Пунктуация в предложении: "Мое предложение"*. Розенталь говорит, что после слова "предложение" всегда ставится двоеточие, а Лопатин этого не говорит.